# Custom Password Django Field for SSN?

Tags: jquery, django

I am using the USSocialSecurityNumberField from django.contrib.localflavor.forms with the PasswordInput widget enabled.

```
ssn = USSocialSecurityNumberField(label='SSN',
required=False,
widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
```

I was originally masking the field with jQuery using:

```
$('#ssn').mask('999-99-9999');
```

This doesn't work as I would like because every character, including the mask '_' and '-' characters with password placeholder characters.  This makes the mask appear like the SSN field is already populated and doesn't assist user with the '-' placeholders.  Is there a built-in solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `django-input-mask` package to achieve this. You can install it using `pip`.

`pip install django-input-mask`

You also need to add `input_mask` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.

To achieve what are you trying to do, you have to create a custom widget.

```
from input_mask.widgets import InputMask

class SSNInput(InputMask):
    mask = {'mask': '999-99-9999'}

class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ssn_field = SSNInput()
```

For more documentation you can see [github page](https://github.com/caioariede/django-input-mask)

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm thanks for the guidelines, I wasn't aware about this.

Comment: Just provided the answer along with the link.

Comment: That is a useful module I didn't know about but it only does what I am already doing.  It is just easier to implement.  The issue is I want a field that has the numbers password masked but preserving the dashes and place holder underscores when the numeric values are blank.  Currently setting it to render as a password will mask even the placeholder characters of the mask.  It's looking more like I will have to write my own solution.